# Html5 video player is not working in ios mobile application?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, vlc, libvlc

I am developing the ionic project(with angular Js ) where I need to play live streaming videos and also mp4 videos for that I tried HTML5 video tag but it wont work on ios.(It is working in Android Mobile Application)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLC cannot run as a web plugin on Android or iOS because those platforms don't support the concept of a web plugin. You need to use a native component. VLCKit and libvlc-for-android are known to run correctly in mixed application environments and we are aware of multiple clients interfacing the native ObjC or Java interfaces through a bridge from a JS context.

Comment: but why it is playing in Android mobile application.